# How to handle Case insensitive xml variables in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

**Input XML:**

```
<root>
<data>
    <Data>
      <rt>ArgoElectrnicsShop</rt>
      <report>
            <row>
                <tn>new tv</tn>
                <value>Samsung</value>
            </row>
            <row>
                <tn>new radio</tn>
                <value>Sony</value>
            </row>
            <row>
                <tn>new WashingMachine</tn>
                <value>Whirlpool</value>
            </row>
        </report>
    </Data>
</data>
</root>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="DataModel">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/data/Data/rt"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/data/Data/rt[text()='ArgoElectrnicsShop']">
    <xsl:element name="T_New">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../report" mode="check"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="report" mode="check">
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EntireValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="row[substring-after(tn, ' ')]/tn"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Field">
            <xsl:value-of select="row[substring-after($EntireValue, ' ')]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:call-template name="sample">
            <xsl:with-param name="tn" select="translate($EntireValue,$lowercase,$uppercase)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="row[substring-after(tn, ' ')=$Field]/value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sample">
    <xsl:param name="tn"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after($tn, ' ')='TV'">
            <xsl:element name="tv">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after($tn, ' ')='RADIO'">
            <xsl:element name="radio">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="substring-after($tn, ' ')='WASHINGMACHINE'">
            <xsl:element name="washingmachine">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

```
**Output XML:**
<DataModel>
    <T_New>
        <tv>Samsung</tv>
    </T_New>
</DataModel>

**Expected Output XML by running through all rows:**
<DataModel>
    <T_New>
        <tv>Samsung</tv>
        <radio>Sony</radio>
        <washingmachine>Whirlpool</washingmachine>
    </T_New>
</DataModel>
```

1. I want to run the loop for all the rows to get the values.
   The values inside the tn may be of any case, so i have taken the value from the tn of a row and translated it to uppercase and compared the value in the template sample and written the correct values in the output xml.
2. I could not run through all the rows in the xml. Could anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Do you only want to get rows where `tn` contains the string "TV", "RADIO" or "WASHINGMACHINE" (in any case)? It seems to me you're making this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: In your `<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:"/>` definition, you entered `:` instead of a closing quote `'`. Was that a mistake here or also in your original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, your question is not entirely clear. The expected output can be produced quite easily by applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="lowercase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="uppercase">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <DataModel>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/Data[rt='ArgoElectrnicsShop']"/>
    </DataModel>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <T_New>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="report/row"/>
    </T_New>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(substring-after(tn, ' '), $uppercase, $lowercase)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:element>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this assumes a number of things - most importantly that the string following the space in the value of `tn` is a valid XML element name.

Comment: Hi, i have two requirements. 1. Handle the case insensitive XML element names eg., I can have a XML element name as <TotalCost> or <totalcost> or <Totalcost> or <totalCost>. I will not know in which case the totalcost element will be. This is one of my requirement and another one is I may have the value inside the XML element may be case insensitive. Like I'm the above example when I try to call a template like the below how it will work for the case insensitive values for the below example

Comment: <xsl:template match="row[substring-after(tn, ' ')='washingmachine' or substring-after(tn, ' ')='WashingMachine' or substring-after(tn, ' ')='Washingmachine' or substring-after(tn, ' ')='washingMachine' ]>

Comment: I'm the above example I have four possibilities so I can check all the possibilities. If there are more possibilities, how I can handle it. For example: PowerSavingMobilePhone word has 16 possibilities. How I can handle this in a simple way

Comment: @ArUn I think the above answers your question. If not, you need to edit your question and show an example of input where the above would not produce the expected result.