# How to handle case insensitive values of the xml variables in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <data>
        <Data>
            <rShop>ArgoElectrnicsShop</rShop>
            <report>
                <row>
                    <tableName>new tv</tableName>
                    <value>Samsung</value>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <tableName>new radio</tableName>
                    <value>Sony</value>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <tableName>new WashingMachine</tableName>
                    <value>Whirlpool</value>
                </row>
            </report>
        </Data>
    </data>
</root>
```

**Generalised XSLT(All the xslt will be called from this)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stlyesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fn="www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:include href="ArgoElectrnicsShop.xslt"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Documents">
            <xsl:element name="DataModel">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/data/Data/rShop"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stlyesheet>
```

**ArgoElectrnicsShop XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stlyesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fn="www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root/data/Data/rShop[text()='ArgoElectrnicsShop']">
        <xsl:element name="T_New">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../report" mode="check"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="report" mode="check">
        <xsl:variable name="EntireValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="row[substring-after(tableName, ' ')]/tableName"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Field">
            <xsl:value-of select="row[substring-after($EntireValue, ' ')]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:call-template name="sample">
            <xsl:with-param name="tableName" select="translate($EntireValue,$lowercase,$uppercase)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="row[substring-after(tableName, ' ')=$Field]/value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="sample">
        <xsl:param name="tableName"/>
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring-after($tableName, ' ')='TV'">
                <xsl:element name="tv">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring-after($tableName, ' ')='RADIO'">
                <xsl:element name="radio">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="substring-after($tableName, ' ')='WASHINGMACHINE'">
                <xsl:element name="washingmachine">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stlyesheet>
```

**Output XML:**

```
<Documents>
    <DataModel>
        <T_New>
            <tv>Samsung</tv>
        </T_New>
    </DataModel>
</Documents>
```

**Expected Output XML by running through all rows:**

```
<Documents>
    <DataModel>
        <T_New>
            <tv>Samsung</tv>
            <radio>Sony</radio>
            <washingmachine>Whirlpool</washingmachine>
        </T_New>
    </DataModel>
</Documents>
```

1. I want to run the above xslt for all the rows and get the expected output.
2. I have a input XML with three rows, one generalised.xslt and ArgoElectrnicsShop.xslt. The values of the tableName XML element is case insensitive.  I would like to check a condition like below
   **xsl:template match="row[substring-after(tableName, ' ')='washingmachine' or substring-after(tableName, ' ')='WashingMachine' or substring-after(tableName, ' ')='Washingmachine' or substring-after(tableName, ' ')='washingMachine']**
   In this example, I have four possibilities. So I can check all the possibilities. For example: PowerSavingMobilePhone word has 16 possibilities. How I can handle this in a simple way.
3. I may have the XML element name also as case insensitive. For eg., rShop or RShop or rshop or Rshop.  I will not know in which case the rShop element will be. So how i check the below

   Here the rShop can be of any case. Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: You should test for `matches` using a RegEx instead of strict equality `=` in your `xsl:when test`

Comment: Simon, How I can use the RegEx

Comment: Not so sure about the syntax : `<xsl:when test="matches(substring-after($tableName, ' '),'TV', 'i')">` the `'i'` makes it case insensitive

Comment: Thanks Simon. One more question **<xsl:template match="/root/data/Data/rShop[text()='ArgoElectrnicsShop']">** Here the rShop can be in any case like rshop or RShop or Rshop or rShop. How I can check for the case sensitive here

Comment: This has been answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081189/regular-expressions-in-xsltemplate-match-attribute see bottom of 2nd answer : see if you can `match="*[matches(...)]"`

Comment: @Simon There is no support for regex in XSLT 1.0 - which apparently is the version used by OP.

Comment: @ArUn Please explain why this question should not be closed as duplicate of your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089480/how-to-handle-case-insensitive-xml-variables-in-xslt

Comment: @michael.hor257k, the solution that you have provided works if I have only one xsl. When I have a generalised XSL and call another XSL like the above example, it's not working.

Comment: This apply templates goes to the new xslt <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/data/Data/rShop"/>

Comment: @michael.hor257k. This apply templates goes to all the templates(Generalised XSL and in the xslt's that was included in the generalised xsl) and checks whether which template has to be applied. I have tried and I could not find a solution, that's why I have asked this question. I have provided what is the expected output as well. Could you provide me the solution

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you already had `xsl:include` in your main stylesheet. I still don't see why you need to split the process so, but I have posted an answer showing how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given these two XSLT stylesheets:

**XSLT 1.0 (this is the "generalised xsl" that will be called by the transformation engine)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:include href="New.xslt"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Documents>
        <DataModel>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data/Data"/>
        </DataModel>
    </Documents>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**New.xslt**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="lowercase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="uppercase">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <T_New>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="report/row"/>
    </T_New>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(substring-after(tableName, ' '), $uppercase, $lowercase)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:element>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result, when applied to your input example, will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Documents>
   <DataModel>
      <T_New>
         <tv>Samsung</tv>
         <radio>Sony</radio>
         <washingmachine>Whirlpool</washingmachine>
      </T_New>
   </DataModel>
</Documents>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I would like to apply the templates in generalised xslt like this **<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/data/Data/rShop"/>**. Because I will be having one xslt for every rShop.  So now in the ArgoElectrnicsShop xslt, I will be checking whether the rShop value is ArgoElectrnicsShop <xsl:template match="/root/data/Data/rShop[text()='ArgoElectrnicsShop']"> and like the same I will checking for another shop CexShop in CeXShop xslt

Comment: I would like to split the process as I will have many include in the generalised xslt. <xsl: include href="ArgoElectrnicsShop"/> <xsl: include href="CeXShop"/>. I will be having some common fields in generalised xslt which will be applied whenever some rShop inpit file is passed to the generalised xslt

Comment: You cannot (easily) apply templates to `rShop` because it has no data. But you can easily identify the `Data` element you want each stylesheet to operate on by using a *predicate*, for example: `<xsl:template match="Data[rShop='ArgoElectrnicsShop']">`.